# Cross referencing Stacks using export variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Given that I have following stacks -

Stack-A

- Output variable with export name `output-resource-1`

Stack-B

- Has a parameter named `base-stack-name` which will be initialized to Stack-A during `sam deploy`

Stack-C

- Has parameter named 'parent-stack-name' which will be initialized to 'Stack-B' during `sam deploy`

Now in Stack-C, I am trying to use resource exported in Stack-A. However Stack-C parameters can only accept one stack name as a parameter which is 'Stack-B'.
Idea is to use the reference to Stack-A available in Stack-B to access the export variable in Stack-A while creating Stack-C.

So I tried using something like this

Output section of Stack-A definition

```
  StackAResource:
    Description: StackAResource.
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: Database.Endpoint
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: ${AWS::StackName}-outout-resource-1
```

Stack-C definition where above exported resource is trying to be accessed.
Stack-C has a parameter named `parent-stack-name`

```
- Name: SomeResource
  Value:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      Fn::Sub:
        - ${stackAexportvariable}-output-resource-1
        - stackAexportvariable:
              Fn::Sub: ${parent-stack-name}-base-stack-name
```

The `sam deploy` for Stack-C keeps failing and I am not sure how I can get this to work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I could easily add another parameter for Stack-C `base-stack-name` and access the exported variable. However as Stack-C is already accepting `parent-stack-name`, which has the information about `base-stack-name` , trying to get rid of additional user input.

Comment: Have you considered using parameter store instead? And pass the parameters instead of using exports, this way you wont have a dependency if stack A has to be changed and stack C could import the parameter

Comment: And could you post the error that is displayed when deploying stack C

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not save the error. However I solved the issue by re-exporting resources of Stack-A in Stack-B and then using them in Stack-C via reference to Stack-B (passed in as a parameter while Stack-C creation).  Sorry for the confusion. Thank you for your comment though.